SHIFT+CRTL+END not working in new Dell keyboard on Ubuntu 22.04
I changed my Dell G3 3500 Keyboard recently. It's working well on Windows (dual boot), but when I try to type SHIFT+CTRL+END in Ubuntu, nothing happens. All three simultaneous keys when pressed do not work. I updated BIOS, no fix.
What I tried
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo service keyboard-setup restart
sudo reboot

Nothing
dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-input
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
sudo reboot

Also no fix.
However CTRL + SHIFT + END works.
Any ideas on this ?

What is Ctrl+Shift+End supposed to do? And in what context do you use it? Shift+End should select all text to the end of the line if you are using it on text. I don't know what Ctrl+Shift+End would do. And does it actually work or not? You say "However CTRL + SHIFT + END works" after the commands you ran. So have you fixed it? Please [edit] your question and clarify.
